# How to get the smallest list?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I got four Lists:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3
1, 2
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

What is the easiest way of getting the one with smallest size in elements (list.size())?

Comment: Is this an array of arrays?

Comment: How do you have those 4 lists? Assuming it's a list of lists: `listOfLists.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(List::size)).get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you named your Lists, so I'm just going to call them List a, b, c and d.

```
public List<?> getLongestList(List<?> a, List<?> b, List<?> c, List<?> d) {
  if (a.size() >= b.size() && a.size() >= c.size() && a.size() >= d.size()) return a;
  if (b.size() >= a.size() && b.size() >= c.size() && b.size() >= d.size()) return b;
  if (c.size() >= a.size() && c.size() >= b.size() && c.size() >= d.size()) return c;
  if (d.size() >= a.size() && d.size() >= b.size() && d.size() >= c.size()) return d;
  return null; //impossible to reach
}
```

I know this is a very ugly solution, but it's easy to understand for java beginners, which I assume you are. If two or more Lists have the same size and are the longest, the first one of those will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the optimal solution would be as follows

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> getSmallestList(ArrayList<Integer>... input) {
            ArrayList<Integer> returnValue = null;
            if (input.length > 0) {
                returnValue = input[0];

                for (ArrayList<Integer> inputIterator : input) {
                    if (inputIterator.size() < returnValue.size()) {
                        returnValue = inputIterator;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No input provided");
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

The `...` parameter allows the method to be called with any amount of variables you like.